# Is there any way to disable these suggestions in Google Keep?

Tags: google-keep

On my Android, Google Keep suggesting some items on checklists.

[image]

On my web browser for PC, I was able to disable these with a Ublock filter. However, on the Android app obviously, that won't work.

Is there any way to disable these suggestions in Google Keep?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Support - Don't Suggest Shopping List Items](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/210950207?msgid=211023134),

> There is no native method to prevent Google Keep from suggesting shopping list items. [...]. In order to solve my problem, I had to work around it. Here are my steps for Android 13:
>
> 1. Go to Google Assistant settings.
> 2. Go to Notes & Lists
> 3. Go to "Select your notes & lists provider."
> 4. From the app selection, choose an app that is not currently installed on your phone.
>
> Now that Keep is no longer your phone's notes and lists provider, checklists behave as checklists - only.

Comment: I believe I did that already, but when trying to check again I get a "403" error when opening Notes & Lists.  That was last night.   I tried it again right now and same thing.  Google sucks!